# Parse values in the url not working(HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed)

Tags: python

Greetings Team Good Day,

I am using the urlib code to print the response data but getting the HTTP error, I have attached the error screenshot and the code in the post, request your advise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s0tf.jpg)

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.google.com/search'
values = {'q': 'python programming tutorials'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

request = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

`HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Type the code and error directly in the question; don't post screen shots.

Comment: Additionally getting the error as below, kindly have a look:

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Comment: Use a GET request

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful. Please, include the code and stack trace in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a POST method, which is not allowed in this url:

```
>> request.get_method()
'POST'
```

Google search expects a GET.

Every time you include the `data` in the request, it will automatically be a POST. But instead, you can do this directly:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('{0}?{1}'.format(url, data))
```